# Copy and paste a range n times

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to what I think is pretty simple but haven't found a solution after searching for the past couple of days.

The goal is to go from this:

```
a b c
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

To:

```
a b c 
a b c
a b c 
a b c
a b c 
a b c
a b c 
a b c
a b c 
a b c
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
```

The code should find the bottom of the range and the furthest column to the right then copy and paste 10 times without a msg box.

Here is the code but it just copies the first row:

```
Sub test()
Dim n As Integer, rng As Range
'n = InputBox("type the value of n")
Set rng = Range("a1")
rng.Select
line2:
n = InputBox("type no. of times you want to be repeated minus 1 for e.g if you wnat to be repeated 3 times type 2")
Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(n, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Range(rng, rng.Offset(n, 0)).PasteSpecial
Set rng = rng.Offset(n + 1, 0)
If rng = "" Then
GoTo line1
Else
GoTo line2
End If
line1:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("a1").Select
MsgBox "macro over"

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub RepeatRange()
    Dim rng() As Variant, rows As Long, n As Integer, i As Long

    rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    n = InputBox("type no. of times you want to be repeat the range")

    For i = 1 To UBound(rng)
        Range("A" & (n * i) - (n - 1) & ":A" & n * i).Value = rng(i, 1)
        Range("B" & (n * i) - (n - 1) & ":B" & n * i).Value = rng(i, 2)
        Range("C" & (n * i) - (n - 1) & ":C" & n * i).Value = rng(i, 3)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRpt()
    Const lNumRepts As Long = 10 '<--change as required
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range, RW As Range

'Results to start in row two below the Source Data
Set rRes = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(rowoffset:=2)

Set rSrc = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
'Copy each row in Source Data to Results range
For Each RW In rSrc.Rows
    RW.Copy rRes.Resize(rowsize:=lNumRepts)
    Set rRes = rRes.Offset(rowoffset:=lNumRepts)
Next RW
End Sub
```

Note that CurrentRegion will be the region starting at A1 that will be bounded by empty cells.

I did not overwrite the original, but that is easily done if needed: